# How do I suppress App Engine logging while running unit tests?

Tags: google-app-engine, nosetests, suppress, suppressmessage

I'm using **gaetestbed** in my GAE app, and it's working very well. However, the useful statements that **nose** prints when your test is incorrect is being washed away by App Engine's logging:

```
root: Level 9: Evaling filter expression "datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 85, _app=u'tipfy') == datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy')"
root: Level 9: Evaling filter expression "datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy') == datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy')"
root: Level 9: Evaling filter expression "datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 86, _app=u'tipfy') == datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy')"
root: Level 9: Evaling filter expression "datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy') == datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 87, _app=u'tipfy')"
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 28 tests in 3.605s
```

Is there a way to suppress this so I can get the clean `something != something else` error messages only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a stupid way,

find capture.py and logcapture.py in your nose/plugins/

find function `addCaptureToErr` in both files, then revise it.
(I don't know which one is the right one, please test yourself)

original code should look like this:

```
def addCaptureToErr(self, ev, output):
    return '\n'.join([str(ev) , ln('>> begin captured stdout <<'),
                      output, ln('>> end captured stdout <<')])
```

change it into

```
def addCaptureToErr(self, ev, output):
    check_errmsgs(output)
    return '\n'.join([str(ev) , ln('>> begin captured stdout <<'),
                      output, ln('>> end captured stdout <<')])

def check_errmsgs(self,errmsgs):
    for i in range(len(errmsgs)-1,-1,-1):
        item = errmsgs[i].split(":") 
        if(item[2].find("Evaling filter expression")):
            #find msgs you want to ignore
            del errmsgs[i]
```

It should works.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this will work in gaetestbed, but using django-nose I can add the following to my settings.py:

```
NOSE_ARGS = ['--logging-clear-handlers', '--logging-filter=-root']
```

Another work-around is to just inverse grep the output:

```
./manage.py test 2>&1 | egrep -v "^(root|Level)"
```

Comment: The suggested nose arguments do the job (at least it does 4 years after the question was asked :)), and much cleaner than patching nose src code. Try this one first.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Bigbear's suggestion, but I did find a quick workaround to the problem: **pipe the err output into a file.**

```
python run_nosetests.py 2> failures.tmp
gedit failures.tmp &
```

This allows you to see a clean printout of your errors at the top of the file, and a minimized output of App Engine logging beneath it.